# 15000 connections to sql server 2008 in “sleeping” status

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I have set `pooling=false` in my connection string and i check in my `sql server 2008` there is 15000 connection is in sleeping status. I cannot understand why this is happen. My server is freeze. Need some help to resolve it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe because you've set `pooling=false`.

Comment: Plus on top you very very likely do not - clean up properly. If in C# you do not close / dispose the connection objects, guess what happens ;) And a connection object is SMALL on the C# side, so you can have a lot without triggering a garbage collection.

Answer (score 5):

I assume the reason is that you've set `pooling=false`. You should always close the connections in your code best by using the `using`-statement:

```
using(var myCon = new SqlConnection("Connection-String"))
{
    myCon.Open();
    // ....
} // will be closed automatically
```

If you would use Connection-Pooling you could "close" the connection without having the underlying physical connection really being closed. That's managed by the pool. If you don't use it you have to manage it yourself. If you don't close connections they will keep *sleeping*.

[SQL Server Sleeping Status and Connection Pooling](http://dinesql.blogspot.de/2010/07/sql-server-sleeping-status-and.html)

Why have you disabled it at all? My advice is: if there is no compelling reason against,  enable it again.

Answer (score 0):

sleeping means it's waiting for its next command from the application or client and in sleep state it isn't using any resources.

SQL Server by itself will not kill any connection/process unless the service is initiated for a restart.

You can do a `restart` of the `SQL Server Service` in case you want to start afresh but in production that may not be the option cause it will incur downtime.

(OR) you can `kill` those inactive process manually as mentioned by @Remush.

use `sp_who` or `sp_who2` which will list out the `PIDS` then use `kill PID`

Comment: Those can be cleaned up w/o downtime, simply use [`KILL`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173730.aspx) in a loop.

Comment: @RemusRusanu, yes that's also a possibility.